# Issue with filtering on Distinct items via T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to code  a T-SQL code in Caspio.

Basically:

- I have a view (`view_all_navs`) with all the data
- I want to filter on unique `Fund_ID`'s that are mentioned in the column (`tbl_funds_Fund_ID`)
- I am trying to sum the numbers in a column (`tbl_funds_Total_Commitment`)

-> I get a blank output... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to everyone for the help :)

Here's my code:

```
ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT(tbl_funds_Fund_ID)) 
       AND (SELECT SUM(tbl_funds_Total_Commitment) 
            FROM _v_view_all_navs 
            WHERE tbl_funds_created_by_investor = '[@field:Investor_ID]' 
              AND tbl_navs_Date <= [@calcfield:8]), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_funds_Fund_ID, SUM(tbl_funds_Total_Commitment) 
FROM 
    _v_view_all_navs 
WHERE 
    tbl_funds_created_by_investor = '[@field:Investor_ID]' 
    AND tbl_navs_Date <= [@calcfield:8]
GROUP BY
    tbl_funds_Fund_ID
```

Comment: Hi Marc- unfortunately it doesn't work.. Just a blank output.. shouldn't I use the DISTINCT instead of the group by?

Comment: Ok I have found it ... Just needed to do = date instead of <=. .. Thanks anyway Marc for your time !